# How to get the result of Ajax call in an alert box

Tags: javascript, ajax

when i am using the ajax within the javascript function to retrieve some value , instead of retrieving the responsetext value in any of the field(eg:`document.getElementbyId("").innerHTML=.....respnseText)` on the page, want to get it as an alert.Can anyone Please help..

Comment: you actually answered your own question when you said alert! :)

Comment: Actually are you sure you didn't mis-spell responseText as "respnseText"

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the `alert()` method:

```
 alert(myAjaxRequest.responseText);
```

Comment: I always feel like I am racing to answer these questions because I know someone is typing the same thing I am :)

Comment: Doesn't help when the OP actually answered it himself as he typed the question either

Answer (score 1):

wouldn't it just be

```
alert(responseText);
```

Since the obvious answer is not working, try this (jquery):

```
$.get('foo.html', function(responseText) {
  alert(responseText);
});
```

if not using jquery, and just using a raw xmlhttp object, you could try this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "foo.html", true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText)
    }
}
xmlhttp.send(null)
```

Comment: okay, then it might be a async issue. What library are you using to do ajax, jquery?

Comment: simply using ajax within javascript function to retrieve value from other page...alert(xmlhttp.responseText);

Comment: Can you try looking at this with Firebug in Firefox? Is the ajax call working?

Comment: ya when i am printing the responseText result in a field value in the page...its getting displayed...but not showing as an alert